# are there mistakes in the sentence I've written?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, colombia

I'm writing an application for doing volunteer work in Colombia. They asked me when I would be able to work and I wrote this:

> Me gustaría trabajar con ustedes de lunes a jueves en la jornada de la tarde. Es que también pienso a seguir unas clases de español. Si este horario no funciona para ustedes, avísame y tal vez puedo acomodar mi horario. Todavía no me he inscrito a las clases.

Does this sound natural? It sounds somewhat off to me. I'm not sure about use of *acomodar* and *inscribir* in this context neither. How would you write this?

Would really appreciate the input, getting the volunteer job would make my travel in Colombia more fulfilling. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this site we do not accept questions with text corrections and for sure your question will be flagged to be closed but since you are coming to **Colombia** and you will be studying Spanish **and also doing volunteer work** I'll try to help.

*Me gustaría trabajar con ustedes de lunes a jueves en la jornada de la tarde* This first sentence is ok.

The next sentence is *Es que también pienso a seguir unas clases de español.* and here "*a seguir*" is not correct. You could change that to "***tomar***" o "***coger***". In some countries "coger" sounds very wrong but in Colombia you can safely say *"Es que también pienso coger unas clases de español"* or *"Es que también pienso tomar unas clases de español".

The next sentence "*Si este horario no funciona para ustedes, avísame y tal vez puedo acomodar mi horario.*" has inconsistencies. If you say "ustedes" you are using plural so the rest of the sentence has to be plural too so *avísame* should become "*avísenme*" or "ustedes" become "ti" but you only use "tu" with people you already know and you are very familiar with.

The alernatives are:

> Si este horario no funciona para **ustedes**, **avisenme** y tal vez pued**a** acomodar mi horario.
>
> Si este horario no funciona para **usted**, **avíseme** y tal vez pueda acomodar mi horario.
>
> Si este horario no funciona para **ti**, **avísame** y tal vez pueda acomodar mi horario.

And the last sentence should be "Todavía no me he inscrito **en** las clases."

Comment: Don't worry. It is just a matter of how you ask. Just read on the help (top right of the page) and ask away. We hope to see you again here on this SE and good luck in Colombia. BTW What city will you be traveling to?